# Why is my output "4 10 7" instead of "4 3 10 7" when i write the following code

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, treemap

I am trying to count the number of set bits are present in a number and arranging the numbers in the ascending order according to the count of the set bits.

My input is :

```
1
4
3 4 7 10
```

Expected Output is:

```
4 3 10 7
```

My output is:

```
4 10 7
```

Why is it skipping 3 when displaying?

```
package practice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
public class MonkAndTasks {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int k = 0;

        while (k < t) {
            long n = Long.parseLong(br.readLine());
            String str = br.readLine();
            String ar[] = str.split(" ");
            int i = 0;
            HashMap<Integer,Long> hm = new HashMap<Integer,Long>();
            while (i < n) {
                Long a = Long.parseLong(ar[i++]);
                hm.put(count(a), a);
            }
            TreeMap<Integer,Long> tm = new TreeMap<Integer,Long>(hm);
            Collection < Long > c = tm.values();
            for (Long e: c) {
                System.out.print(e + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    static int count(Long n) {
        int c = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            n = n & (n - 1);
            c++;
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

When I print the value a to check whether a reads the value 3 or not, it turns out that it is reading the value 3 but after passing value to hashmap and treemap yet the desired output is not displayed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the 4 numbers (`4 3 10 7`) as values in a `TreeMap` where the key seems to be the number of `1` bits (I think that's what `static int count(Long n)` does). `3` and `10` both have 2 `1` bits (11 and 1010 respectively), so `10` replaces `3` in the `Map` (since a `Map` doesn't allow duplicate keys), and `3` is never output.

Basically, the following loop

```
while(i<n)
{   
    Long a=Long.parseLong(ar[i++]);
    hm.put(count(a),a);
}
```

inserts the following entries to the TreeMap :

```
hm.put(1,4);
hm.put(2,3);
hm.put(2,10); // this entry has the same key as the previous entry and therefore
              // replaces it
hm.put(3,7);
```

Comment: So how can i store n values having same keys ?

Comment: @MihirMehta You can use a `TreeMap<Integer,List<Long>>`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Eran